# Load a theme for Aquamacs from the .emacs file

Tags: emacs, themes, aquamacs

I managed to choose various themes from within `Aquamacs` but the problem is that if at some later point I have an error in my `.emacs` then the theme's setting is broken. Therefore I decided to load it directly from the `.emacs`.

I found several options and neither works. The best I could make is to add the following:

```
(load-file "~/Library/elisp/themes/zenburn-theme.el")
```

This works fine if I evaluate it manually (`C-x C-e`), but it is **not** loaded automatically by Aquamacs when it starts.

Note, if I click `Adopt Face and Frame Parameters as Default`, then the situation is better, but still the `zenburn` theme is not loaded properly. It is only loaded OK if I manually load it as I just described.

By the way, trying to use the `color-theme` package like:

```
(require 'color-theme)
(color-theme-initialize)
(color-theme-snow)
```

for instance, yields a similar problem and the theme is not loaded properly.

I would like to use the `zenburn` theme - how should I do it with `aquamacs`?

Answer (score 0):

Move the theme to `~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs/` or add `~/Library/elisp/` to your `load-path` like this:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/Library/elisp/themes/")
```

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry for that mistake. I edited the answer.